# how to send ctrl + c to another screen?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, metacharacters

I am trying to send ctrl + c to another screen.

How can I do this?

```
screen -S railsServer -p 0 -X stuff $'\cc'

screen -S railsServer -p 0 -X stuff $'^C'
```

However these don't seem to work.

Comment: Both of these seem to work for me in a quick test.

Answer (score 1):

```
screen -S railsServer -p 0 -X stuff $'\003'
```

If someone can explain what the `$'\003'` represents that would be awesome!

Comment: \003 is equivalent to Ctrl + C

Comment: `man ascii`. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html is what I look at usually. But as is often the case, wikipedia has the last word: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart . Good luck to all.